# When I press a button in my app ,the whole app freezes

Tags: ios, swift

My app has 3 components:

1. A textfield where the user enters a number to see if the number is prime or not
2. A button that when pressed does an action to determine if the number is prime or not
3. A label that shows whether the number is prime or not

When the button is pressed, the whole app freezes(but does not crash)and I have no idea why. I tried searching about this online, but none have solved my problem.Is there anything I can check for errors, or what reasons can a button freeze an app.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var i = 2

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if let userEnteredText = text.text{
            var isPrime = true
            let number:Int = Int(userEnteredText)!

            while i < number{
                if number % i == 0{
                    isPrime = false
                    i = i + 1
                }

                if isPrime == true{
                    label.text = "\(number) is Prime"
                    label.textColor = UIColor.black
                }else{
                    label.text = "\(number) is not Prime"
                    label.textColor = UIColor.black
                }
             }
        }else{
            label.text = "Error-Enter a positive integer"
            label.textColor = UIColor.red
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please update your answer with part of the code which you think might cause the problem.

Comment: Ok, may take 5 minutes

Comment: Can I just put all my code?

Comment: It is your call. Yes of course you can post the entire code here.

Comment: The text is the text in the textfield and the label is the label I talked about.

Comment: You're likely entering an endless loop

Comment: What do you think I should change?

Comment: If it doesn't start out with a value that happens to match `number % i == 0` you'll never get out of that loop because `i` will never be incremented.

Comment: Oh, sorry for wasting your guy's time.

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the i++ should be outside of the if statement

```
...
        while i < number{

             i = i + 1            

             if number % i == 0 {
                isPrime = false
            }
...
```

Please note : Since you are trying to compute something that can take sometimes, you'll have(when you learn a little more) to do this kind of computation outside of the main thread. Your apps locks because you are blocking the main thread which is the one controlling the UI/touch/interaction of your app. Look into [dispatch_async](https://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1)

PPS : Learn how to point break point in XCode and step over/into, you'll be able to debug the flow of your app.

Comment: you probably also want to define the var i = 2 inside the buttonPressed function instead of globally